# Can I use the SHA-224 encryption in Dialogflow Node.js?

Tags: node.js, encryption, hash, dialogflow-es, sha

I am trying to encrypt user input and compare with the encrypted string in database in dialogflow.

How can I add in the crypto package into package.json and get the SHA-224 to work in the index.js?
I have tried my code but nothing happened.

Python code to encrypt data for comparison later:

```
import hashlib
import pandas as pd
strings = []

data = pd.read_csv("DBDATA.csv")
df = data[['ID']]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    b = row["ID"].encode('utf-8')
    print(b)
    hashed = hashlib.sha224(b).hexdigest()
    strings.append(hashed)
data["NUMBER"] = strings
```

Javascript code to encrypt user input:

```
  const crypto = require('crypto');

  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha224');
  var string = agent.parameters.adminnumber;
  var hashedString = hash.update(string, 'utf-8');
  var gen_hash= hashedString.digest('hex');
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "crypto": "4.0.0"
  }
```

[Dialogflow Nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdVTm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code work well for me (using a hardcoded "string" var). Maybe you don't see anything because you don't log the result.

Remember install the `crypto` package using `npm install crypto --save` command or just `npm install` if dependency already exists into `package.json` file.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const hash = crypto.createHash('sha224');
const string = "Test SHA-224 crypto.";
const hashedString = hash.update(string, 'utf-8');
const gen_hash= hashedString.digest('hex');

console.log(gen_hash); // Trace the result
```

Note: `var` keyword makes the baby jesuschrist cry

Comment: Oh my thanks for that! Anyway, is my dependencies for crypto correct? hehe

Also, after getting the gen_hash,  I'm actually comparing it with the database data to snapshot the key. 

`var ref = admin.database().ref("NUMBER");
    ref.orderByValue().equalTo(gen_hash).
on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      id = snapshot.key;
    });`
My database stored hashed string should be able to match up with the one in node.js right? Since it is both sha224?

Comment: @user16381662 Yes, if both values are in sha224 must be equals. My crypto version is "1.0.1" when install it for your example but this package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module (depending of your nodejs version). I recommend you remove dependency from package.json and reinstall it using the command `npm install crypto --save`.